# Что значит строка

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! что значит эта строчка?

```
id = id || App.params;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оставить id как есть если  [`Boolean(i)===true` (не false,0,null,пустая строка, см ссылку)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), либо (`если Boolean(i) === false`) присвоить значение из App.params.

пример:

```
var default=3
function show_value(i) {
i=i || default; //обратите внимание, тут нет var, т.к. переменная уже в scope функции 
                // потому-что она в аргументах
console.log(default);
}

show_value(); //3
show_value("test"); //test
show_value(0); //3
show_value(false); //3
var a;
show_value(a); //3;
a=true;
show_value(a); //true
```

более универсально использовать строку типа:

```
i=i!==undefined?i:App.params; //только undefined, т.е. отсутствие аргумента в предыдущем примере, либо передан аргумент `undefined`
```